# Multiple forms in one JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

There are two buttons in a JSP page. One of them will show a student registration form and the other one will show a teacher registration form. BUT IN THAT PARTICULAR JSP PAGE. I.e. I actually want to use two forms in a Single JSP page. On page load, both of them will be hidden. By clicking the two buttons, respective forms will be shown.

How is it possible?

Comment: Someone procrastinated instead of doing their homework? ...

Comment: If it is urgent, pay someone to do the job :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need put the form inside `<div>`, and if the guy click here or there you use jquery or javascript to do:
div style block or hide.

Comment: I just tell what you should do, not how you do. You have half of solution. The other half you can search by yourself. Gl on that.

Comment: That's more than I would've given him, but +1 for pointing in the right direction without really giving up the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery and css combined into the jsp just include jquery and css on header part of the jsp.the below link is usefull to you.
[click here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)